# How can I display a 'last-deployed' timestamp from within my Heroku Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, continuous-deployment

I'd like to update an environment variable or something to track the time of the deploy that is currently active. Is there any way to do this automatically from within my app on Heroku, or do I have to do it as part of a deploy script? Ideally, I'd like something that would work with me using TDDium for CI, and letting them do the push to Heroku for me when the build passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
There is no automatic method when deploying to Heroku unless you make a deploy script/task. (I searched for this too in June 2012). I have a rake task that does a deploy, part of it sets GIT_TAG and my web page (application layout in rails) prints that to the page.

Heres how I write to the Heroku GIT_TAG config var (using a Rails-based Rake task):

```
    tag = `git describe master --always`.strip
    `heroku config:add GIT_TAG=#{tag} --app XXXX`
```

2.
With tddium: tddium now supports a "post build hook" and I augment their standard version to set the GIT_TAG during that process. read and follow http://blog.tddium.com/2012/05/09/heroku-continuous-deployment/ first and to the "post_build_hook" task add something to read the tag and set the heroku config var as demonstrated:

```
    namespace :tddium do
      def cmd(c)
        system c
      end

      desc "post_build_hook to deploy to dfc-site-qa"
      task :post_build_hook do
        ...use code verbatim from above URL (https://www.tddium.com/support/reference#customization)
        ...
        current_tag = `git describe master --always`.strip
        cmd "heroku config:add GIT_TAG=#{current_tag} --app XXXX" or puts "could not set GIT_TAG to #{current_tag}"
        ...
      end
```

Notes:

1. Substitute for 'master' in the above as needed. In my deploy rake tasks (happy to share) I allow deploying based on a branch or a tag (handy to bypass heroku's desire to only deploy from master).
2. To have tddium run your "post_build_hook" you must de-activate the post-deploy URL by running this:
   tddium suite --edit

   and use your current value for the "pull url" but set the "push url" to blank (or default). This step was not mentioned on the blog link.
3. In your tddium web page for the current build you will now see a link to the post_deploy_hook logfile (at very bottom of page) that you can open and see how it went (aka debug your rake task).

Answer (score 10):

#### Use Environment Variables on Heroku

You could use Heroku's [config-vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). These are really just environment variables that you configure through the Heroku CLI. For example, you could store the current date in an environment variable named DEPLOY_TIMESTAMP.

```
heroku config:add DEPLOY_TIMESTAMP=$(date)
```

You should then be able to access this environment variable from within your application or from the command line. The value can be accessed with `ENV['DEPLOY_TIMESTAMP']` from your Rails application, or by parsing the output of `heroku config` from your local project directory.

#### Automate with Aliases

If you want to automate this somewhat, you can create a Git alias to push to Heroku and update DEPLOY_TIMESTAMP at the same time. Please note that you can't overwrite the names of real Git commands like *push*, but you can add a custom action such as *pushstamp*. For example:

```
git config alias.pushstamp \
    '! git push heroku master; heroku config:add DEPLOY_TIMESTAMP=$(date)'
```

#### See Also

[git-config(1)](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)

Comment: Yeah this is similar to what I was thinking, but I have no control over the command that TDDium uses to push my app to Heroku. If I did this on my end, on the push to Github (which kicks off the CI/CD cycle) then if the build failed, my app would be showing the wrong deploy time.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the last deploy time by looking at the timestamps on the files in the read-only Heroku filesystem.

You can verify this by looking at those timestamps directly with ls.  Example from running `heroku run rails c`:

```
irb(main):003:0> puts `ls -la`
total 96
drwx------ 14 u51199 51199  4096 May 14 22:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root   root   4096 Mar 20 09:43 ..
drwx------ 10 u51199 51199  4096 May  7 02:12 app
drwx------  2 u51199 51199  4096 May  7 02:17 bin
drwx------  2 u51199 51199  4096 Mar 14 22:12 .bundle
drwx------  5 u51199 51199  4096 May  7 02:12 config
-rw-------  1 u51199 51199   226 May  7 02:12 config.ru
drwx------  3 u51199 51199  4096 May  7 02:12 db
-rw-------  1 u51199 51199  1138 May  7 02:12 Gemfile
-rw-------  1 u51199 51199 11456 May  7 02:12 Gemfile.lock
-rw-------  1 u51199 51199   542 May  7 02:12 .gitignore
drwx------  5 u51199 51199  4096 May  7 02:12 lib
drwx------  2 u51199 51199  4096 May  7 02:17 log
-rw-------  1 u51199 51199    57 May  7 02:12 Procfile
drwx------  2 u51199 51199  4096 May  7 02:13 .profile.d
drwx------  3 u51199 51199  4096 May  7 02:17 public
-rw-------  1 u51199 51199   249 May  7 02:12 Rakefile
-rw-------  1 u51199 51199   613 May  7 02:12 README.md
-rw-------  1 u51199 51199    31 May  7 02:12 .rspec
drwx------  7 u51199 51199  4096 May  7 02:12 spec
drwx------  3 u51199 51199  4096 May  7 02:18 tmp
drwx------  6 u51199 51199  4096 May  7 02:13 vendor
```

As a result, if you want to know when your app was last deployed, you can use `File.mtime` and get back a real `Time` object:

```
irb(main):009:0> File.mtime("app")
=> 2015-05-07 02:12:57 +0000
irb(main):010:0> File.mtime("app").class
=> Time
```

Comment: That's a perfectly working answer and should be the accepted one imho.